# How can I dont show the divisions between cells in this divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have this simple screen of an application in Vue.js:
[Sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYsl9.png)

I want to hide these divisions between cells, in a manner that the lines of the itens are continous.

I had tried to alter the classes of the columns to "col-md" and "col-sd", but witout sucesss.

Here is the code of the template session of the application:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <h1> Animais </h1>
  <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>
                Animais Cadastrados
        <span class="badge badge-info">{{animais.length}}</span>
            </h3>
       
            <ul>
                <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
          Nome
          <li class="list-group-item"  v-for="animal in animais" v-bind:key="animal"> 
            {{animal.nome}}
          </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col"> 
          Idade
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="animal in animais" v-bind:key="animal"> 
            {{animal.idade}}
          </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col"> 
          Raça
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="animal in animais" v-bind:key="animal"> 
            {{animal.raca}}
          </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col"> 
          Informações
           <li class="list-group-item" v-for="animal in animais" v-bind:key="animal"> 
              <i @click="Show" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </li>
          </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>
                h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor. Sed iaculis posuere diam ut cursus. <em>Morbi commodo sodales nisi id sodales. Proin consectetur, nisi id commodo imperdiet, metus nunc consequat lectus, id bibendum diam velit et dui.</em> Proin massa magna, vulputate nec bibendum nec, posuere nec lacus. <small>Aliquam mi erat, aliquam vel luctus eu, pharetra quis elit. Nulla euismod ultrices massa, et feugiat ipsum consequat eu.</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: give a link to the site if the site is hosted.

Comment: Its not hosted, its in my machine.

Comment: local project??

Comment: yes, I am still learning. my girlfrind asked me a system to control her animals vaccine. lol

Comment: it will be easy for me to do this if I open the site through the browser object inspector

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier, you can just copy the generated HTML into JsFiddle. I'm trying to guess what you are trying to achieve and I think you can try something like that:

```
<div class="row"  v-for="animal in animais" v-bind:key="animal">
    <div class="col-md-3">{{animal.nome}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{animal.idade}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{animal.raca}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
          <i @click="Show" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, I'm not sure what you're trying to do but looping 4 times on the same array is probably not the way to go. And yes, you may nest Bootstrap a row inside another.